# Can't make Swift use my Generic == Operator

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My app contains many Core Data NSManagedObject subclasses, all of which have an NSDate which I call their recordID. When comparing two objects, I want to use this data to determine if they are the same. Now since there are many subclasses, I created a protocol to show that they all implement a recordID:

```
protocol HasID
{
    var recordID: NSDate {get}
}
```

Simple, right? Now I have implemented the == operator as follows:

```
func == <T: HasID>(left: T, right: T) -> Bool
{
    return left.recordID == right.recordID ? true : false
}
```

Problem- Swift doesn't use my beautiful == operator and instead compares with some generic crap as follows

```
func ==(lhs: NSObject, rhs: NSObject) -> Bool
```

Now if I implement == for each individual subclass as follows

```
func == (left: Pilot, right: Pilot) -> Bool
{
    return left.recordID == right.recordID ? true : false
}
```

Then it uses my operator and works. (I've also got a == operator implemented for NSDate which is why the above code is fine.)

Any idea how I can get my generic == operator to be used rather than the NSObject one?

Comment: have you declared the == operator outside the class?

Comment: I am not sure, but overriding `==` for managed object subclasses (even if it worked) *might* be a problem, as the NSManagedObject documentation explicitly states that `isEqual:` must *absoluty not* be overridden. – I would recommend to define a custom comparison operator instead.

Comment: Have you conform the `Equatable`?

Comment: Have you extended your managed object subclasses to conform to `HasID`? Just having the `recordID` property isn't enough -- you'll need to explicitly declare conformance: `extension Pilot : HasID { }`

Comment: Yes, I declared the == operator outside the class and yes, I made sure my NSManagedObject subclasses explicitly conform to HasID in addition to equatable. However, interesting point about overriding isEqual: being forbidden. Is that what defining the == operator does? If so, why do I not need to use the word override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting together previous comments and proposal, it seems it is due to `NSManagedObject`.

Put the following code in a playground:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

protocol HasID
{
    var recordID: NSDate {get}
}


func == <T: HasID>(left: T, right: T) -> Bool
{
    println("==")
    return left.recordID.isEqualToDate(right.recordID)
}

func ~= <T: NSManagedObject where T: HasID>(left: T, right: T) -> Bool
{
    println("~=")
    return left.recordID.isEqualToDate(right.recordID)
}

class Managed: NSManagedObject, HasID {
    let recordID: NSDate = {
        let components = NSDateComponents()
        components.day = 31
        components.month = 3
        components.year = 2015
        let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
        return gregorian.dateFromComponents(components)!
    }()
}

let foo = Managed()
let bar = Managed()

foo == bar
foo ~= bar

switch foo {
case bar:
    println("Equal")
default:
    println("Not Equal")
}
```

As you will see the *overloaded* `==` is never called, but `~=` is.
Thus I suggest not going too far forcing `NSManagedObject` to use an overloaded `==` and use `~=` instead. As you can see, you will get it to work in `switch` statements as well (in fact it is the pattern match operator).

If you play removing `NSManagedObject` from my example, you will see that for an ordinary class, your solution would work.

My opinion is that `==` operator for `NSManagedObject` is used to compare between managed object ids, and not pointers in memory. The *same* managed object could have different pointers in memory when it is present in different managed object context. That's why I wouldn't try to overload it. It helps keep track of the same managed object in different context.

Comment: Probably, in the end, you will prefer a custom function `areEqual` or something, to avoid bugs due to the similarity between `==` and `~=` ;-)

Comment: Well, this solves my problem. I'm a little confused as to what makes NSManagedObject so special, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an infix operator:

```
// I've modified your protocol just for my example

protocol HasID
{
    var recordID: Int {get}
}

infix operator <*> {
    associativity right
}

func <*> (left: HasID, right: HasID) -> Bool
{
    return left.recordID == right.recordID ? true : false
}

// example:

class Fake: HasID {
    var recordID = 1
}

class Bull: HasID {
    var recordID = 1
}

let fake = Fake()
let bull = Bull()
if fake <*> bull {
    println("is equal")
}
```

Comment: This also solves my problem. If I could give two green checkmarks I would, but since I can't I put it on the one below with more explanation. Thanks for the help though!